# For every $w \in \mathbb{C}$ there exists a sequence {$z_n$} in $\mathbb{C}$\ {0} such that $z_n \rightarrow 0$ and $e^{1/z_n}\rightarrow w$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that for every $w \in \mathbb{C}$ there exists a sequence {$z_n$} in $\mathbb{C}$\
{0} such that $z_n \rightarrow 0$ and $e^{1/z_n}\rightarrow w$.

When $w=0$ I can take $z_n=-1/n$, then $\lim_ne^{1/z_n}=0$. But what should I do when $w\neq0$? Hope someone could help me out. Thanks

Comment: $\exp$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$. Appeal to Casorati-Weierstraß

Comment: Or to Picard's thm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea(For $w\neq0$).Let $$K=log|w|+iArg(w)\implies e^{K+i2n\pi}=w,n\in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\implies e^{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{K+i2n\pi}}}=w, \frac{1}{K+i2n\pi}\rightarrow0,n\rightarrow\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of $e^z$ (or basic properties of it, depending on perspective).  It is periodic ($e^{z+2\pi i}=e^z$ for all $z$), so there are always inputs with arbitrarily large absolute value giving whatever output you want. In fact $0$ is the only value of $w$ for which you can't let $e^{1/z_n}$ be exactly $w$ for each $n$, with explicit formulas for $z_n$ being elementary, and you already solved it in case $w=0$.

Comment: Is it clear that periodicity is enough to give any output desired? Surely there is more to it than that. How does this process, for example, give a sequence converging to say $\sqrt{2}+\pi$?

Comment: Adam Hughes: It is easy using basic properties of $e^z$ to find $z_0$ such that $e^{z_0}=\sqrt 2+\pi$.  Now let $z_n=\frac{1}{z_0+2\pi n i}$.

Comment: @AdamHughes what about the answer given by Donald?

Comment: @Heisenberg: Donald has made explicit the elementary solution I wanted to suggest without giving details.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks

Comment: @JonasMeyer The other answer too says the same thing right?

Comment: @Heisenberg: Is my last comment unclear?

Comment: @JonasMeyerSorry I saw it just now